# What does "hit" mean in today's headline?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

Can anybody tell me the meaning of "hit" in this CNN headline: "[British bank takes $125 million hit from Brexit risks](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/10/26/investing/brexit-rbs-share-price/index.html)".

I've looked up the word in several dictionaries, but I can't find any suitable definition.

Thanks a lot.

Best,

Comment: The "damage" is financial in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Hit here is used metaphorically meaning a loss, a financial loss. The complete idiomatic expression is ***[Take a hit](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-a-hit)***:

> to suffer damage or loss.
>
> - Clothing took the biggest hit, with sales down by 35%.

(Macmillan Dictionary)

From Green’s Dictionary of Slang, ***[Take a hit:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/7gykq5q#z3aj44i)***

> 1. [2000s] to suffer.
> 2. to lose value.